# find all companies where all employees in specific state

Tags: postgresql

I have a table `employees` with columns:

- `company_id`,
- `id`,
- `opt_state` (`ceased_membership`, `ignition`, `opted_out`, `opted_in`),
- `opt_out_on`.

I want to query all companies where all employees `opt-state` is `in ('ceased_membership', 'ignition', 'opted_out')` and the date `opt_out_on` when last employee left.

I have tried this but it didn't work

```
select company_id from employees where id=all(select id from
     employees 
      where opt_state in ('ceased_membership', 'ignition','opted_out')
```

Then I wrote this query below, which worked very well and gave me the resolution I was looking for. However, I'd like to ask here if this can be done differently, more elegantly.

```
SELECT
  e.company_id
  , max_opt_out
FROM (
       SELECT DISTINCT
         company_id
         , count(id)
           OVER (
             PARTITION BY company_id ) opt_out
       FROM employees
       WHERE opt_state IN ('ceased_membership', 'ignition', 'opted_out')) e
  LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT
                company_id
                , count(id)       opt_in
                , max(opt_out_on) max_opt_out
              FROM employees
              GROUP BY company_id) S
    ON e.company_id = s.company_id
WHERE e.opt_out = s.opt_in;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a good time to use the HAVING clause

```
SELECT company_id, max(opt_out_on)
  FROM employees e
  GROUP BY company_id 
  HAVING bool_and( opt_state in ('ceased_membership', 'ignition','opted_out'));
```

`HAVING` in a bit like a `WHERE` but the condition apples to whole `GROUPS`

bool_and is an agregate function that is only true when all the records in the group are result in true.

Comment: thank you so much, it's really perfect and highlighting bool_and is wonderful as I have never used it before as I am new to PostgreSQL and DB in general

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that you want to query a maximum `out_out_on` for each company that only have employees in a set of states, which means that do not have any employee not in a set of states.

So, translated to SQL:

```
select company_id, max(opt_out_on)
from employees e
where not exists(
    select 1 from employees
    where company_id=e.company_id
    and opt_state not in ('ceased_membership', 'ignition','opted_out')
)
group by company_id;
```

Comment: thank you some much it worked and way faster than what i wrote